# Android Launcher app - Pressing Home Button in other Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-launcher, android-homebutton

I've written a custom Launcher that has three activities. I looked up the sample *home* app and configured the intent filters accordingly for the main activity - that is the first activity which is launched at start - `android.intent.action.MAIN`. Let's call it **Activity A**.
In this **Activity A** I'm able to control what the HOME button does by dispatching the `KEYCODE_HOME` KeyEvents - which is all and well.
However once I move to another Activity in the same Application, let's call it **Activity B** I'm no longer able to override the Home Button.

Is there any way to capture the `KEYCODE_HOME` KeyEvents in other Activities within the same launcher app? Are there any other intent-filters for the other two Activities that I should consider?

I've used the home sample app as a reference and I've applied the same actions and intent-filters. I also use the same `public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)` method. I know that you're not allowed to capture the `KEYCODE_HOME` KeyEvents unless your App is a `HOME` app.